The indeterminacy of computation
This is my second attempt at understanding the argument put forward by James Ross against computationalism. But even years later, I still can't wrap my head around it.
The argument builds on Samuel Kripke's original observation: If we define a quus function ⊕:

x ⊕ y = x + y, if x, y < 57;
= 5 otherwise.

and we observe a computational machine calculating, but with x, y < 57, we don't actually know if it calculates x + y or x ⊕ y.
In fact, for any computational machine we'll never know if it performs normal addition: there will always be another alternative function that fits the output because there remains an upper bound for the highest number that was ever used in the calculations. We can't avoid the indeterminacy in physical processes, yet thought is determinate, and by this, it follows that thought must be immaterial.
But the problem that I have with this argument is that functions like additions can be constructed from simpler, finite functions.
And for the physical instantiation of those finite functions, it seems we can dodge the issue if we demand that modules have a finite, observable set of states.
So let's do this for the plus-example. We have a machine that can read numbers from two tapes (where every field contains a digit 0–9 or blank) and has one output tape. It calculates the sum of the numbers and prints the result on the output tape. Its components are:

a module that calculates the addition of three numbers a, b < 10 and a carry ≤ 1 (the black box marked with “+”)
two reader modules (marked with “R”) to read from the input tape (blue and yellow), and send the data to the addition module
one memory module for the carry (green, marked with “C”), in which the addition module stores and retrieves the carry (either 0 or 1)
three motors (gray) to advance the tapes one cell after the addition was performed for a digit
one printer (“P”) to print the resulting digit on the output tape (pink).


The operation is self-explanatory: At the start, carry memory contains 0. The addition module (AM) gets digits a, b from readers and the carry memory; then performs addition a + b + carry (with blanks interpreted as 0). The lower digit of the result is sent to the printer. If the result > 9, the carry memory will be set to 1, otherwise to 0. The AM requests all motors to advance their tapes by one cell. The AM will halt if it reads blanks from both input tapes and a zero from the carry memory.
So if we do the whole thing for the example (dot marks a carry = 1):

Now for this machine, we can determine that it implements addition by observing the components and their connections, if we assume that:

modules do not contain hidden states
modules can only be affected via their input connectors, never by their output connectors (in the diagram, the directions of the connectors are represented by the arrowheads).

Now, sure, those assumptions are already idealizations. We're talking about abstract modules, not real ones. A real physical module will fail to achieve them, since unintentional defects and breakdowns will occur (which can be understood as a hidden state, e.g. “after the trillionth digit always output 0”).
But this problem would also happen with idealizations of finite physical patterns as finite mathematical structures. E.g. a real Rubik's Cube will break after long use and not follow the rules of the Rubik's Cube group.
So in James Ross' argument, is infinity a decisive ingredient? Why? What does it actually add? Doesn't it boil down to the same old, well-known problems as Nelson Goodman's “grue-bleen” and John Searle's “syntax is not semantics” argument?
EDIT: Here is a dissertation solely about the argument. And here a presentation of it by the author.

I don't see how having simpler functions matters in any way here. Addition itself is also definable directly with a primitive recursive function. Implementing it in some kind of turing machine doesn't make this simpler. The statement "we don't actually know if it calculates x + y or x ⊕ y." doesn't make sense - there is nothing to know, there is no difference between those operations for x, y < 57, so what is there to know? Kripkenstein was not talking about machines or epistemology, but about how meaning is acquired - which is a rather different issue imo.

The semantic issue of the famous rule following paradox here is different from Goodman's grue-bleen which as an intended rule there's no syntactic ambiguity...

@mudskipper well, the position (to be refuted) is: "even though ⊕ and + could not be distinguished since x, y < 57, the disposition of either ⊕ or +  was there nonetheless." Also, this is not directly about Kripke but the argument by James Ross, and he talks about machines.

@mudskipper breaking it down to simpler elements helps, if it allows us to deal with a finite set of input - output combinations. So the behaviour of the simpler "modules" can be fully surveyed (instead of just for a finite subset of an infinite set of inputs). And if we exclude hidden states, we also can exclude surprises, like in the plus vs. quus example.
PS: This question is about James Ross' version and while he's inspired by Kripke, he does talk about computational machines.

@mudskipper I guess, I overlooked the most obvious counterargument: there is a number for which even the whole cosmos isn't large enough for the tape to fit in. Therefore, the machine fails to implement addition. The question is, what to do then? One must progressively reduce the width of the cells of the tape, by a convergent series. E.g. by 1/n²: 1 cm, 0.25 cm, 0.11 cm … = π/6. Which obviously doesn't work, at least according to the laws of physics we know (quantum uncertainty etc.).

You said: "thought is determinate, and by this, it follows that thought must be immaterial". But thought has limitations, just like the machines you are describing, and thought is error-prone. Does this indicate that thought is material?

@ScottRowe Not Mr. Ross here. He's been dead since 2010, but I'll try to steelman his case here. We are talking about formal thinking. The example at hand is adding. Mr. Ross claims that being mistaken while adding is still, even erroneously, adding. That is because adding is a form of understanding.
I think Mr. Ross would also give me license here to quote Mr. Pope: To err is human.
Mr. Pope is also dead.

Dillard surveys Ross's argument, including Feser's later elaborations, and three objections to it in Ross Revisited. Ross never establishes the ideal determinacy of human thought that he needs to claim its unreproducibility by the physical, and what we do actually observe and ascertain can very well be physically implemented. The argument is by intimidation, all sorts of bad things follow without ideal determinacy, but it is unclear how they matter when it is indistinguishable from lesser kinds in practice.

@ScottRowe well, it's not my argument.  If I understood it and accepted it, I wouldn't ask here. Also, Ross' slick, terse and overly “dominant” writing style doesn't help. Still, the idea seems to be that when we think about the finite activity of adding, we understand it as part of something infinite. Our thought is determinate and “picks out” the pure function, while any implementation by a computational machine does not “pick out” the correct pure function. 1/2

But we can also go to the meta-level: computer algebra systems (CAS), like Mathematica, can achieve some generality. It can even calculate the value of an infinite series. But the rules were programmed in by human programmers. It would be the step from understanding a pure function on an infinite domain to getting to rules that represent those infinite properties (as used by a CAS), is something that computers can never themselves do. They never picked out the real pure function in the first place. But seriously, it would be Ross' job to fill the gaps and to make this more convincing.  2/2

Ok, thanks for the background and explanation. I guess I'll stick with Bob Ross. A lot of the rules I follow were programmed in by human programmers. 'Computer' used to be a job title...

@Conifold IMHO, the issue is if humans have some magical power to grasp pure functions on infinite domains, or if they get around the problem by “cheating”. The addition machine above defines the addition function on an infinite domain under the unrealizable assumption that (a) “modules do not contain hidden states” and (b) “tape can be arbitrarily extended”. But why shouldn't a machine be able to implement functional equivalents of the assumptions of (a) and (b)? Perhaps that's just what we do, since we also make mistakes and can't add certain massive numbers. This is too confusing.

@ScottRowe yes, the maths teacher in elementary school drilled into my head that a ⋅ b = b ⋅ a, which I first took as an article of faith handed down by authority. It was named “law of commutativity”, after all, and you better obey the law. But then I imagined multiplication as the area of rectangles: and that “law” is just a consequence of rectangles remaining the same if they're rotated by 90 °. It may well be that computers cannot, in principle, handle infinite concepts like this. Which would make our attempts at Artificial General Intelligence foolish. But I'm not 100% convinced.

When I was about 6 I counted up some dots in a rectangle across, and then down, and got the same number. I showed my father and he said, "Yes, that's multiplication." I thought: someone else already came up with this?!?

@viuser I think it is important to understand that it is irrelevant how well or how far you run the algorithm, either with a machine or as a human. The idea is that human thought understands adding, through instruction or intuition, regardless of any errors. That's how we differentiate between 'adding' and 'quadding'. Also, the article was written in 1992, well before major advancements in AI were realised. As to your suggestion that 'Ross should fill the gaps and make it more convincing': he's been dead for more than 10 years.

@Philomath well, he still had time to plug in the gaps from 1992 to 2010. And if the argument is worth anything, it should still be valid despite all the advancements. But if the advancements refute it, we should clearly state so. PS: IDK if more recent AI technology is fundamentally new from a philosophical perspective. Perhaps LSTM and transformer architecture are just a huge pragmatic improvement? Computer algebra systems were commonplace technology in the 1980s. And artificial neural networks have been known since the 1940s.

I am hopeful that the rapid developments in AI will benefit our understanding of whether and how machines can understand the world. This is still an open question but I see no reason why they couldn't.  I agree that Ross is not convincing but it was interesting to flesh out his argumentation.

It is one issue with Ross's argument, he never explains why epistemic indeterminacy of the physical for us extends to its metaphysics either. But even assuming that it does, the indeterminacy in physical implementation is matched by the like indeterminacy in human thought, imperfect that it is. Our supposed ideal grasp is just the Dunning–Kruger bias, which is propped up by 'cheating' to remove naive indeterminacies, as in using higher order logic to remove indeterminacy in the first order arithmetic, say. But that too is imperfect and as such can be implemented physically on a computer.

@Conifold the Kripke-Ross argument has potential, but it is just too slick. Still, reason allows us to reach vastly beyond ourselves. For example, from the finite practice of counting to potential ∞. From potential ∞ to actual ∞ (which is genuinely more than just the negation of finiteness). From actual ∞ to cardinal numbers, …. Current AI cannot jump those gaps on its own, which is a concrete, practical matter (contrary to Ross' scare talk). But is it in principle incapable of that? … I could see an argument here … or is it just a mirage?

@Conifold the question also is: Why did Kripke only present this argument in a lecture? In the linked dissertation, there are many statements like that Kripke's statements are very unclear / open to interpretation. Then why didn't anybody ask him in his lifetime? Why didn't anybody ask him about potential flaws that dissuaded him from publishing? In all that time! But now it's too late. For the monumentality of the claims made by this argument, it's all extremely obscure, like orally transmitted, esoteric knowledge.

Bob Ross is gone, too :-( - RIP

You ask: So in James Ross' argument, is infinity a decisive ingredient?
The answer is yes.
Your next question: Why?
Ross' argument takes the form of the following syllogism:

All formal thinking is determinate.
No physical process is determinate.
Thus, no formal thinking is a physical process.

It is helpful to understand that the determinency under discussion is semantic determinency.
In order for the minor premise to be true, Ross has to show that physical processes are indeterminate.

No physical process can be that definite in its form in a single case. Adding cases even to infinity, unless they are all the possible cases, will not exclude incompossible forms. But supplying all possible cases of any pure function is impossible. So, no physical process can exclude incompossible functions from being equally well (or badly) satisfied(..)

Ross uses Kripke's Quus function as an example of an incompossible function. Note the caveat: unless they are all the possible cases.
However, later he asserts that the physical process is indeterminate even if the actual should be infinite.

That is because the differentiating point, the point where the behavioral outputs diverge to manifest different functions, can lie beyond
the actual, even if the actual should be infinite; e.g., it could lie in
what the thing would have done, had things been otherwise in
certain ways. For instance, if the function is x(*)y = (x + y, if
y < 10^40 years, = x + y + 1, otherwise), the differentiating output
would lie beyond the conjectured life of the universe.

He uses what is, admittedly, an abstruse argumentation: ..it could lie in what the thing would have done, had things been otherwise in certain ways.
In a footnote, Ross articulates his thesis in a beautiful way:

So "what" addition is cannot be explained by "all the outcomes": rather, each and every outcome is determined by what addition is.


So for a machine process to be fully determinate, every output for a function would have to occur. For an infinite function, that is impossible. The machine cannot physically do everything it actually does and also do everything it might have done.' That is the heart of the matter.

That is the heart of the matter.
The machine or the physical process has no other means to differentiate (and hence to be determinate) between "adding" and "quadding" than to investigate all the actual outcomes of the functions. The machine has no other means because it can not think.

Right, but we didn't design adding machines to think. I don't see the point of all this. To prove that humans are special? They're not. But life is special.

Um, yes. Mr. Ross tries to argue that machines can not think. That they can not possibly think. But humans can think and for this reason thinking must have some immaterial aspect. I think Mr. Ross could be characterised as a Christian philosopher. I'd also like to point out that I am not a subscriber of Mr. Ross' philosphy in any way whatsoever. I was merely answering a question.

@ScottRowe May I ask why you think humans are not special, but life is?

People have assumed and tried to prove that humans have a privileged place in the universe, but it doesn't hold up. But, if we do have privilege, we'd better start taking the associated responsibility for the life on this planet, which as far as we know, does not exist elsewhere.

Well, the challenge with analyzing a physical computer by the method you proposed - examining its components and matching them to some ideal Turing machine - is that a physical computer is not an ideal Turing machine. If you analyze the physical components of a computer, you do not find the ideal mathematical "addition" function anywhere in there. You don't even find limited 64-bit addition in there.
Why? Because real physics is full of edge cases. If we supply the digital inputs for "5" to your computer's adder, and the digital inputs for "7," it is not physically guaranteed that the outcome will be 12. Perhaps it will be correct 9,999,999,999,999,999 times out of 10,000,000,000,000,000, but there is always a chance something weird happens - the adder gets hit with a cosmic ray. Static shock from someone walking on a polyester carpet nearby induces an errant voltage. An earthquake destroyed the computer.
Real computers also physically degrade over time, unlike Turing machines. After 9,999,999,999,999,999 additions, your adder may be past its engineered life. A wire may have (very slowly) chemically reacted causing a short, so it may start giving very inaccurate answers from then on.
So when we say the adder does "64-bit addition," there are implicit caveats. Under implicit normal conditions, the adder does 64-bit addition.
What we have to do, then, is combine the physical computer with an idealized model of it, and we can say that the computer implements the model as long as it does happen to match the results the model says should happen. Sometimes the computer might not match the model, and we'd say the computer was not implementing the model just at that time.
But there are multiple possible models we could use. A "complete physical model" - which the physical computer would always match - is different from a "Turing machine model" - which the physical computer would match almost all of the time, as long as it has enough memory and storage. And that's different from an "instruction set architecture model," which the physical computer might match more of the time, as long as stuff like cosmic rays or end-of-life considerations don't come into play.

People shouldn't be allowed to say "Turing Machine" unless they have programmed for 40 years, and are using it as intended. Of course, I'm relying on Bernoulli's Principle in making this assertion. And some Quantum Indeterminacy for good measure.

Let's talk about your example, first. What you've designed is a tape machine that ostensibly does modulus (mod 10) arithmetic of an odd sort; fine enough. However, what Kripke or Ross would immediately point out is that the physical process that lies inside your (appropriately colored) black box addition module might be doing addition, or might be doing (say) b'addition (which is indistinguishable from addition except under some condition) and you won't know. Say, for instance, that the black box gives proper modulus addition unless the running sum of the numbers of tape 1 reaches a multiple of 1,235,802, at which point your black box systematically adds 3 to the recorded sum. B'addition is clearly not addition, and there are clearly an infinite number of b'addition variants, so you cannot readily be sure what your black box is doing.
The problem is that the black box is not doing addition or b'addition. It is merely undergoing a physical process, and we are using that physical process as an analog for the determinate process of addition. That's how computers work. A computer bit is is a physical component that holds a minute electrical charge; if the charge is above some defined value we interpret it as 'on' and thus '1', while if it's below some value we interpret it as 'off' and thus '0'. But the charge itself is inherently inconsistent and fluctuating, the cutoff values are arbitrary to each machine, and the design is usually forced to incorporate error checking to catch moments when a bit flops when it should have flipped, or where the charge state is indeterminate.
In terms of the bigger picture, I'd read Ross this way. We all know the old saw that the map is not the terrain. In other words, the terrain will always have details, nuances, and features that won't appear on any given map. If we get a map that shows the way to a local grocery, we don't expect that map to show every line and crack in the sidewalk, every tree and shrub we pass, every parked car we have to walk around… That level of information is both useless and impossible to achieve for a map.
But by that same token, Ross is arguing that the terrain is not the map. Maps are sets of rules — determinate systems — for getting from place to place, and necessarily contain information that isn't in the terrain. Just as we cannot reduce the terrain to the map, we cannot reduce the map to the terrain. We can think of addition, logic, etc, as 'maps' for doing certain activities. We cannot impose those 'maps' on the practical world of objects and statements without some degree of interpretation: e.g., we can say we have one apple or one cat or one of those, but we can't comfortably say we have one; we need an implicit or explicit reference. By that same logic, we cannot expect physical processes to capture the essence of one of those 'maps' except by analogy and approximation. But if the map and the terrain are mutually irreducible, then human cognition and physical process are also mutually irreducible.

So, is this the final answer? Can we all put this one aside now?

The human mind does operate by analogy and approximation...

... Which is not to say that we can't make a machine which does likewise. Neural nets, either simulated or directly implemented, are arguably a step in that direction.

@keshlam: I don't think this quite connects with Ross' argument, but I won't disagree with either point.

I'm still having trouble with the assertion that a physical system can't run an (incomplete, approximate, etc.) introspective model of itself. If you want to say this means we may never fully understand ourselves, that's believable... but that's science, and life generally; we accept a practical solution even if we suspect there are details it doesn't capture.

@keshlam: I think that goes well beyond what Ross is saying. Ross' main point is that a physical system can only imitate a formal system like arithmetic or logic; they cannot access a determinate system of such. Maybe it helps to note that physical processes are both analog and continuous: they shift smoothly through states and have no objective boundaries that might constitute 'objects'. 'Objects' only exist in mental spaces, not in the physical world.

@keshlam: Without objects, physical systems are incapable of representing numbers, discontinuous binary states, or functional relations; they can only imitate such through approximate and non-determinate methods. What this really means is that if an AI does come to use arithmetic or logic in a determinate mode, then that ability in the AI will not be reducible to its physical circuits or electrical flows. Ross wouldn't say it's impossible, just that it's due to something other than the physical processes underlying the AI.

@TedWrigley: Your calculator does a better job of representing and manipulating numbers than you do, and a list or other collection of size N works equally well if you insist on it being N of something. I see no need for the nonphysical except in the form of software/wetware running on the physical (which does appear to qualify as his"something other"). I need to read this in detail, but at first glance it appears that he is saying that he doesn't know how to do it, which is very different from saying it can't be done.

@Kehlam: You're really missing the point, here, and I don't want to continue arguing against something that isn't relevant. You should read the journal article linked up top; it addresses your points.

The question seems to have changed a great deal since I answered it. I will need to reread that and the reference.

@TedWrigley I got into the first page and was immediately floored by " adopt a cavalier certainty that our judgments only simulate certain pure forms and never are real cases of, e.g., conjunction, modus ponens, adding, or genuine validity". Since I do not believe in pure forms or "genuine validity", I can stop right there; excluding everything that doesn't support your answer is no way to draw valid conclusions.

Adding is a procedure. Machines already do it perfectly well. There are libraries which will do it for numbers of arbitrarily large size, and do it more reliably than a human can (though errors are possible for either).

Modus ponens likewise, as far as I understand that term. Even if you insist on symbols rather than values, there are tools which will happily do symbolic manipulation. I've used tools which use that and other forms of symbolic logic to optimize hardware. If there's a problem with this one, it's due to his having already excluded the input.

Yes, I should read the full article; he may carve out something useful which isn't present in the problem statement. But by modus ponens etc, if he starts with false assumptions any conclusion can be justified.

Yes, this is grue/bleen on a different axis.
Unavailable data is unavailable data, and until/unless it comes in anything dependent upon it is unknown. That isn't a problem if you are willing to take your best guesses compatible with what is known and winnow/correct them later if necessary to produce models we are increasingly confident in, which is how science works.
It is a problem if you insist on having perfect answer right now, which was important to theologists who worried that guessing wrong might cause them to lead their students into hell, and to philosophers who want certainty.

Well, duh, part of my question was: Doesn't it boil down to the same old, well-known problems as Nelson Goodman's “grue-bleen” Maybe not answer a question with a question?

Rhetorical question removed; analysis retained.

It is similar: Kripke's skepticism is about meaning rather than skepticism about induction, but yeah. Ross then uses Kripke's Quus function to prove that machines can't think. It boils down to the fact that computers can't do all calculations and they don't understand adding as humans do. I read and analysed Ross' article which is quite long and tedious and that is it. The machine described in the question is beside the point and quite irrelevant to Ross' argument.

@Philomath no, the machine isn't irrelevant: The issue is that in Ross' article the indeterminacy depends on the input (e.g. number size). And via the machine we can show the indeterminacy must now solely depend on time because we reduced it to primitive operations, where we can assume that they are executed the same way at different times (not different inputs). So it is not just similar but precisely like the grue-bleen-problem.

I do need to point out that clocked digital computers of their current sizes are only one possible architecture, deliberately designed to conform to a particular set of simplifying abstractions, and that the moment you allow multitasking and attach them to hardware that has a variable response times they stop being fully deterministic. A lot of work is put into designing systems to re-establish deterministic behaviors,, and often that is incomplete. To argue that it is still deterministic one must include the hidden variables and the effort put into hiding them. Analog async is worse. BT, DT.

@viuser With all due respect, if you think the machine is relevant then I don't think you understand the article. Ross: So "what" addition is cannot be explained by "all the outcomes": rather, each and every outcome is determined by what addition is. He is saying that no matter what machine you use, it will not understand, i.e. it will not get the meaning of addition. Humans do, machines don't, and that is Ross' argument.

@Philomath but focusing on understanding would make it an argument about semantics, which is not the issue here. Ross OTOH claims that constancy over time is not allowed to be assumed for a machine. Ross: “even if we used up all the suitable numbers, the function itself would still be repeatable, say, for the same additions, but now done in a different order”. (⇒ no constancy over time!)

@viuser even if we used up all the suitable numbers. Good luck building a machine that goes to infinity and back. It is merely Ross' infelicitous way of expressing that it really doesn't matter how good your machine is. In other words it is irrelevant. Do you understand what the argument is about? What Ross is trying to argue?

@Philomath Yes, sure. And since the claim is nothing short but monumental (reason cannot be explained materialistically), Ross needs to exclude many strange machines that one could come up with! Sure, I agree that any digital computer we'll build in the near future will be a finite state automaton. But can we really exclude infinite processes in the material realm? Is that the meaning of “material”? I'd say no. So it is extremely brash to exclude machines that employ such processes from the analysis, and that could be used to fully realize a function like addition.

We can't even seem to come up with agreed definitions of reasoning, so that should happen first. One good thing about my Programming job is that no one will put me or my users in Hell if I get something wrong. Although it can get mighty uncomfortable sometimes. I need one of those huge pencil erasers that says, "I never make BIG misteaks" (sic)

@viuser I don't agree with Ross' conclusion and I think it's perfectly possible for machines to think in the future (NNs). As so often on this forum, a question is asked about a certain philosophical argument. To answer the question and steelman the position doesn't mean that one subscribes to that view..

@ScottRowe See my comment to viuser. Ex-programmer myself.
